# Layout is not displaying properly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

![enter image description here][1]I am using custome listview and using xml file for each list item but  it is not giving output as per my requirment my list items xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:height="150dp"
          android:background="@drawable/bar_bg_thin"
           android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
         >
        <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                  android:paddingTop="5dp"
                  android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                  >
                <ImageView
                 android:layout_gravity="left|top" 
                  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                  android:id="@+id/image"
                  android:src="@drawable/stub"
                   android:layout_width="100dp" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
  <TableLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
            >
            <TableRow>       
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    />
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>          
                 <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>
              </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


       </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
```

It is not displaying images on its full view i am loading images runtime from server i want image display in full view not half and i also want to increase height of this list item

i want images to dispaly in full size and also want to increase the size of each item of listview

Comment: please give screenshot of your layout which you want

Comment: give me ur e mail i will send u image here it is not allowing me to upload image

Comment: I have sent you the screen shot of my layout

Comment: This two link may help you                                               http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html                                                          http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: they are usefull but their row size is not increased as i want

Comment: what happern if you set this two properties of imageview android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="0dip" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Ur changes are working but it still not increasing the size of row

Comment: android:layout_width="100dp" and place android:layout_width="wrap_content"